# Is there a way to record the audio output of a certain application on OSX programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-audio

```
Is there a way to record the audio output of a certain application(for example only record chrome while chrome is playing video and apple music is playing music) on OSX programmatically? Does it need to implement an audio driver to achieve it?
```

Is there a way to record the audio output of a certain application(for example only record chrome or itune while chrome is playing video and apple music is playing music) on OSX programmatically? Does it need to implement an audio driver to achieve it?

Comment: There is an open sourced Chrome Audio Capturer extension https://github.com/arblast/Chrome-Audio-Capturer with solid ratings, perhaps that would be a good start

Comment: @Kamil.S Thanks. That works for me with chrome. But I want to record any application's audio without any limit